# linuxでの共有ライブラリのリンクについて

Tags: linux, c, makefile

linuxでmakefileを書く際に、以下のような共有ライブラリのリンクの仕方が分からず、困っています。

【やりたいこと】
[実行ファイル]-->[libA.so]-->[libB.so] という依存関係
libA.soを作るためのMakefileに-lBと記述し、実行ファイル側を作るためのMakefileには-lA　とだけ記述したい。

【現状】
私が書いているMakefileだと、実行ファイルを作るためのMakefileに　-lA -lBと記述しないとリンクエラーになってしまいます。

シンプルなMakefileのサンプルなどあれば教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: お使いのコンパイラは gcc でしょうか？

Comment: はい、gccです。バージョンは4.8.1です。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ld のエラーメッセージに促されるまま -rpath を付けたら通りました。
こんな感じで。

```
all: exe

exe: main.c liba.so
    gcc -o exe main.c -L. -la

liba.so: a.c libb.so
    gcc -c -fPIC a.c
    gcc a.o -shared -o liba.so -L. -Wl,-rpath,. -lb

libb.so: b.c
    gcc -c -fPIC b.c
    gcc b.o -shared -o libb.so

clean:
    -rm -f exe liba.so libb.so
```

gcc 5.2.0, ld 2.25.1 です。

Comment: `-rpath` だと実行時のライブラリ検索パスに `.` (カレントディレクトリ) が含まれてしまいますよ。

Comment: そうですね。別案がありましたらお願いします。

Comment: `-rpath-link` がリンク時のパスの設定ですね。環境変数`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` を設定するのと同じ効果ではないかと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、試してみます。

Answer (score 1):

こちらの環境ですと、masm さんの結果と挙動が異なります。

```
$ uname -rvm
3.19.0-28-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 31 15:52:10 UTC 2015 i686

$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.1.1-4ubuntu12) 5.1.1 20150504

$ ld --version
GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.25
```

**a.c**

```c
int func1(int n) {
  return 2 * n + 3;
}
```

**b.c**

```c
int func2(int n){
  return n * n + 3;
}
```

**main.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int func1(int n);
int func2(int n);

int main(){
  printf("func1: %d\n", func1(10));
  printf("func2: %d\n", func2(10));
}
```

**Makefile**

```
CC = gcc

SRCS = main.c
LIBA_SRCS = a.c
LIBB_SRCS = b.c
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-rpath=. -L.

main: libA.so
    $(CC) $(SRCS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) -lA

libA.so: libB.so
    $(CC) $(LIBA_SRCS) -fPIC -shared -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) -lB

libB.so:
    $(CC) $(LIBB_SRCS) -fPIC -shared -o $@
```

```
$ make main
gcc b.c -fPIC -shared -o libB.so
gcc a.c -fPIC -shared -o libA.so -Wl,-rpath=. -L. -lB
gcc main.c -o main -Wl,-rpath=. -L. -lA
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccn7p3N0.o: undefined reference to symbol 'func2'
./libB.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

`libA.so` 内には `func2` が存在しませんのでエラーとなってしまいます。これを解決するには以下のオプションを使います。

> ld(1)
>
> --copy-dt-needed-entries
>
> This option also has an effect on the resolution of symbols in dynamic libraries. With --copy-dt-needed-entries dynamic libraries mentioned on the command line will be **recursively searched**, following their DT_NEEDED tags to other libraries, in order to resolve symbols required by the output binary.

つまり、

```
$(CC) $(SRCS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) -lA
=>
$(CC) $(SRCS) -o $@ -Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries $(LDFLAGS) -lA
```

とします。

```
$ make main
gcc b.c -fPIC -shared -o libB.so
gcc a.c -fPIC -shared -o libA.so -Wl,-rpath=. -L. -lB
gcc main.c -o main -Wl,--copy-dt-needed-entries -Wl,-rpath=. -L. -lA

$ ./main
func1: 23
func2: 103
```

ld 2.5.1 では `--copy-dt-needed-entries` がデフォルトなのかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

最適かどうかはわかりませんが、実行時のライブラリー検索パスを指定できる環境変数 `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` を利用すればいけますね。

```
CC=     LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. gcc -fPIC -L.
LDSHARED=   $(CC) -shared

all: exe

exe: main.c liba.so
    $(CC) -o $@ -la main.c

liba.so: a.o libb.so
    $(LDSHARED) -o $@ -lb a.o

libb.so: b.o
    $(LDSHARED) -o $@ b.o

clean:
    -rm -f exe *.so *.o
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、試してみます。